# Why is glDrawElements() not drawing anything?

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I've seen a couple of questions about the same topic but still couldn't figure out what was wrong with my code.

It worked to get a window running, where a keypress would change the background color with `glClearColor()`.

But now, when trying to draw a quad onto the screen, the screen stays black.
A little summary of how I think it should work:

How `mesh` is created:

```
public Mesh(Vertex[] verts, int[] indices) {
    this.verts = verts;
    this.indices = indices;
}

//Differend class
public Mesh mesh = new Mesh(new Vertex[] {
        new Vertex(new Vector3f(-0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f)),
        new Vertex(new Vector3f(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f)),
        new Vertex(new Vector3f( 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f)),
        new Vertex(new Vector3f( 0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f))
    }, new int[] {
        0, 1, 2,
        0, 3, 2
    });
```

For initializing the game, this is called:

```
public void create() {
    vao = GL30.glGenVertexArrays();
    GL30.glBindVertexArray(vao);

    FloatBuffer positionBuffer = MemoryUtil.memAllocFloat(verts.length * 3);
    float[] positionData = new float[verts.length * 3];
    for (int i = 0; i < verts.length; i++) {
        positionData[i * 3] = verts[i].getPosition().getX();
        positionData[i * 3 + 1] = verts[i].getPosition().getY();
        positionData[i * 3 + 2] = verts[i].getPosition().getZ();
    }

    positionBuffer.put(positionData).flip();

    pbo = GL15.glGenBuffers();
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, pbo);
    GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer, GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    GL20.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL11.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    IntBuffer indexBuffer = MemoryUtil.memAllocInt(indices.length * 3);
    indexBuffer.put(indices).flip();

    ibo = GL15.glGenBuffers();
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo);
    GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer, GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}
```

And lastly, the `mesh` should be rendered with this:

```
public void renderMesh(Mesh mesh) {
    clear();

    GL30.glBindVertexArray(mesh.getVAO());
    GL30.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, mesh.getIBO());
    GL11.glDrawElements(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES, mesh.getIndices().length, GL11.GL_FLOAT, 0);
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    GL30.glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

I've checked that the methods are actually invoked by using `System.out.println`.
The game's input still works. It's just that the screen is black and not showing any quad.
Why is it not drawing anything onto the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type argument which is set to `glDrawElements` hs to correspond to the index buffer, rather than the vertex buffer.
In your case it has to be `GL_UNSIGNED_INT` rather than `GL_FLOAT`. See [`glDrawElements`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/glDrawElements.xhtml).

<s>`GL11.glDrawElements(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES, mesh.getIndices().length, GL11.GL_FLOAT, 0);`</s>

```java
GL11.glDrawElements(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES, mesh.getIndices().length, GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
```

Note, `GL_FLOAT` is not an accepted value for `glDrawElements` and will cause an `INVALID_ENUM` error.

Comment: When using eclipse, will that error show up in the error log?

Comment: @Vinegare01 OpenGL errors have to be retrieved in the application by [`glGetError`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/glGetError.xhtml)

Comment: Or, much better, via the [debug output feature](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Debug_Output). Also, gl debuggers will typically show these errors, too.